# Affect scoping in SQL stored function

Tags: postgresql

The condition `staff.staffId = staffId` in the following stored function apparently always evaluates to `true` because `staffId` is scoped to the (inner) column in table `staff` instead of the (outer) argument of the function `endpoint_organizations`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION endpoint_organizations (staffId INTEGER)
RETURNS TABLE (organizationId INTEGER, name TEXT)
AS $$
  SELECT organizations.organizationId, name 
  FROM organizations
  INNER JOIN staff
  ON staff.organizationId = organizations.organizationId
  WHERE staff.staffId = staffId
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

Is there are way for affecting the scoping in a concise way that does not require changing the name of the argument e.g. into `staffId1`. I've tried changing the condition into `(staff.staffId AS staffId1) = staffId`, but that does not seem to work.

Comment: Don't name your parameters the same as columns.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name That's the "changing the name of the argument e.g. into `staffId1`"-solution already mentioned. Isn't there another alternative?

Comment: See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-implementation.html#PLPGSQL-VAR-SUBST for various options but it's really better to rename the variables

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name OK, I shall rename the variables then. If you like to write this up as an answer, I shall accept it. Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-implementation.html#PLPGSQL-VAR-SUBST)

> You can also set the behavior on a function-by-function basis, by inserting one of these special commands at the start of the function text:
>
> ```
> #variable_conflict error
> #variable_conflict use_variable
> #variable_conflict use_column
> ```

But for readability (and maintainability) I would strongly suggest to rename the variable to something different.

Many people simply use a prefix for the parameters (e.g. `p_staff_id`) and also prefixes for local variables (e.g. `l_some_var`) to make sure they never clash with each other or column names (this is also the de-facto standard in the Oracle world)

Comment: Thx for the extra info re best practices (in the Oracle world).